# Angular JS Filter is not getting applied in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

I have an element of input type search. I am not able to apply filter on this.

```
<label class="item-input-wrapper" style="font-size:20px!important;">
  <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
  <input type="search" style="width:45%;font-size:20px!important;" placeholder=" Search" ng-model="searchText.text">
</label>
```

Here in this case filter is not being applied, where as if I don't use `ng-if`, I am able to apply filter. Please help as I don't want to remove `ng-if` as I have some reason to keep it.

```
<div class="w-clearfix product-row" ng-show="isListViewShown" **ng-repeat="product in arrayOfProducts | 
        filter : searchText.text " ng-if="$index % 4 === 0">**
                        <div class="_4-col" ng-if="$index < 
        arrayOfProducts.length">
                           product.name 

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it may be helpful to you.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

$scope.searchText = '';

$scope.names = ['India','America','Japan','Denmark','Russia','Landon','Cuba','Finland','Italy','Shrilanka','Australia','Brazil','Canada'];
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<input type="search" ng-model="searchText" />
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter : searchText" ng-if="$index % 4 === 0">
    {{ x }}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```